# Как рекурсию переделать в итеративный метод.(Diamond-Square)

Tags: c#, алгоритм, unity3d, генерация-случайных-данных

Вот [тут](http://unity3d.ru/distribution/viewtopic.php?f=18&t=30363) человек говорит:

> переделал все в итеративный метод, чтобы корректно считалось по слоям

У меня такая-же ситуация есть методы, только не знаю как их вызывать послойно?
Я не могу зарегистрироваться на этом форуме, что бы спросить его.
Там же на форуме он кратко объясняет принцип работы алгоритма.

> Попытаюсь объяснить. 
> Метод Square на вход получает два угла, левый нижний и правый верхний и считает центральную точку заданного таким образом квадрата. 
> Diamond принимает на вход только координаты точки, которую надо посчитать (т.е. середины квадрата из предыдущего шага) и половинную сторону этого квадрата, считает координаты четырех точек справа, слева, сверху и снизу от принятой точки и также, как и в Square, усредняет их и прибавляет случайное число, пропорциональное стороне. Если любая из координат этих четырех точек выходит за границы карты, то он берет значение точки, лежащей с другой стороны, т.е. как бы сворачивает плоскость. 
> Метод DiamondSquare комбинирует эти два метода, принимая те же параметры, что и Square. Сначала он вызывает Square для входного квадрата, потом Diamond для всех четырех середин своих сторон, а потом рекурсивно вызывает сам себя для четырех под-квадратов до тех пор, пока не посчитает все пиксели.

Сама рекурсивная функция:

```
public void diamondSquare(Vec2int L, Vec2int R, int l)
{
    if (l > 0) {
        Vec2int[] points = GetPoints(L, R, l);
        foreach (Vec2int elem in points) {
            diamond (elem, l);
        }
        square (L, new Vec2int (points [3].x, points [2].y), l);
        square (new Vec2int (points [3].x, points [2].y), R, l);
        square (points [0], points [1], l);
        square (points [3], points [2], l);

        diamondSquare (L, new Vec2int (points [3].x, points [2].y), l / 2);
        diamondSquare (new Vec2int (points [3].x, points [2].y), R, l / 2);
        diamondSquare (points [0], points [1], l / 2);
        diamondSquare (points [3], points [2], l / 2);
    }
}
```

Остальной код:

```
public int size = 32;
[Range(0,1f)]
public float Roughnees = 0.5f;
private float[,] map;

public void square(Vec2int L, Vec2int R, int l)
{
    Vec2int Center = new Vec2int (R.x - l, R.y - l);
    float a = map [L.x, L.y];
    float b = map [L.x, R.y];
    float c = map [R.x, R.y];
    float d = map [R.x, L.y];
    map [Center.x, Center.y] = (a + b + c + d) / 4 + Random.Range (-l / (size - 1) * (Roughnees), l / (size - 1) * (Roughnees));
}

public void diamond(Vec2int point,int l)
{
    float a, b, c, d;

    if (point.y - l >= 0)
        a = map [point.x, point.y - l];
    else
        a = map[point.x, size - l];  

    if (point.x - l >= 0)
        b = map [point.x - l, point.y];
    else
        b = map [size - l, point.y];

    if (point.y + l < size)
        c = map [point.x, point.y + l];
    else
        c = map [point.x, l];    

    if (point.x + l < size)
        d = map [point.x + l, point.y];
    else
        d = map [l, point.y];

    map [point.x, point.y] = (a + b + c + d) / 4 + Random.Range (-l / (size - 1) * Roughnees, l / (size - 1) * Roughnees);
}



public static Vec2int[] GetPoints(Vec2int L, Vec2int R, int l)
{
    return new Vec2int[] {
        new Vec2int (L.x, L.y + l),
        new Vec2int (R.x - l, R.y),
        new Vec2int (R.x, R.y - l),
        new Vec2int (L.x + l, L.y)
    };
}
public struct Vec2int
{
    public int x;
    public int y;
    public Vec2int(int x,int y){
        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;
    }
}
```

***Так-же я был бы рад ссылкам на то что можно почитать в этом направлении.***

> Важно заметить, что эти две высоты, которые достались нам на предыдущем шаге, должны быть уже посчитаны — поэтому обсчет нужно вести «слоями», сначала для всех квадратов выполнить шаг «square» — затем для всех ромбов выполнить шаг «diamond» — и перейти к меньшим квадратам.

Из [статьи](https://habrahabr.ru/post/111538/) на хабре.

В моём случае рекурсия уходит в глубь для левого нижнего квадрата и каждая его правая и верхняя стороны неверно считается, и только после того как эта рекурсия заканчивается, начитается следующая для правого верхнего, для которого тоже неверно считаются левая и нижняя стороны.

Количество вызовов методов на первых 3 итерациях при разрешение картинки 64px 
1 x Square и Diamond
4 x Square и Diamond
16 x Square и Diamond
И для каждого метода нужно знать координаты.

Comment: Будет корректней, если вы переместите сюда код, который нужно переделать в итеративный

Comment: ...причем из этого кода будет по максимуму выброшена ненужная детализация.

Comment: Я напишу, как только доберусь до компьютера :) Есть общий метод до таких штук.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Пару дней я только размышлял как решить мою проблему, начал смотреть в сторону yield, изучал его(правда так практически ни чего о нем и не понял), сегодня принялся экспериментировать с ним, и в это время пришла небольшая идея, которую я реализовал отказавшись от yield в процессе. 
В общем проблема решена, картинка генерируется правильно и достаточно быстро, с настройкой разрешения и шумности.
Вот такие картинки генерирует:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сам код:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Global;
using UnityEngine;

public class DiaSqu : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int size;
    public float Roughnees = 0.5f;

    Material mat;
    float[,] map;
    Texture2D GeneratedTexture;

    void Awake()
    {
        size++;

        mat = gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material;
        GeneratedTexture = new Texture2D(size, size);

        map = new float[size, size];
        map[0, 0] = Random.Range(0.3f, 0.6f);
        map[0, size - 1] = Random.Range(0.3f, 0.6f);
        map[size - 1, size - 1] = Random.Range(0.3f, 0.6f);
        map[size - 1, 0] = Random.Range(0.3f, 0.6f);

    }
    void Start()
    {
        Vec2int Left = new Vec2int(0, 0);
        Vec2int Right = new Vec2int(size - 1, size - 1);

        List<Box[]> box = new List<Box[]>();
        box.Add(new Box[] { new Box(Left, Right) });

        for (int l = size; l > 0; l /= 2)                                                                 //Генерация
            box = Generate(box);

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)                                                                    //Запись в текстуру
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
                GeneratedTexture.SetPixel(i, j, new Color(map[i, j], map[i, j], map[i, j], 0));

        GeneratedTexture.filterMode = FilterMode.Trilinear;
        GeneratedTexture.Apply();
        mat.mainTexture = GeneratedTexture;
    }
    public List<Box[]> Generate(List<Box[]> input)
    {
        List<Box[]> next = new List<Box[]>();
        foreach (Box[] Arr in input)
            foreach (Box item in Arr)
                next.Add(Square(item));
        foreach (Box[] Arr in input)
            foreach (Box item in Arr)
                diamond(item);
        return next;
    }
    public Box[] Square(Box box)
    {
        Vec2int Center = new Vec2int(box.R.x - box.HalfLength, box.R.y - box.HalfLength);
        map[Center.x, Center.y] = (map[box.L.x, box.L.y] + map[box.L.x, box.R.y] + map[box.R.x, box.R.y] + map[box.R.x, box.L.y]) / 4 + Random.Range(-box.Length * Roughnees / (size - 1), box.Length * Roughnees / (size - 1));
        return new Box[]{
            new Box(box.L,Center),
            new Box(Center,box.R),
            new Box(new Vec2int (box.L.x, box.L.y + box.HalfLength),new Vec2int (box.R.x - box.HalfLength, box.R.y)),
            new Box(new Vec2int (box.L.x+box.HalfLength, box.L.y),new Vec2int (box.R.x , box.L.y+box.HalfLength))
        };
    }
    public void diamond(Box box)
    {
        float a, b, c, d;
        Vec2int Center = new Vec2int(box.L.x + box.HalfLength, box.R.y - box.HalfLength);
        Vec2int[] points = new Vec2int[] {
            new Vec2int (Center.x-box.HalfLength,Center.y), //Left
            new Vec2int (Center.x,Center.y+box.HalfLength), //Top
            new Vec2int (Center.x+box.HalfLength,Center.y), //Right
            new Vec2int (Center.x,Center.y-box.HalfLength)  //Bottom
        };
        foreach (Vec2int point in points)
        {
            if (point.y - box.HalfLength >= 0)
                a = map[point.x, point.y - box.HalfLength];
            else
                a = map[point.x, size - 1 - box.HalfLength];
            if (point.x - box.HalfLength >= 0)
                b = map[point.x - box.HalfLength, point.y];
            else
                b = map[size-1 - box.HalfLength, point.y];
            if (point.y + box.HalfLength < size - 1)
                c = map[point.x, point.y + box.HalfLength];
            else
                c = map[point.x, box.HalfLength];
            if (point.x + box.HalfLength < size - 1)
                d = map[point.x + box.HalfLength, point.y];
            else
                d = map[box.HalfLength, point.y];
            map[point.x, point.y] = (a + b + c + d) / 4 + Random.Range(-box.Length * Roughnees / (size - 1), box.Length * Roughnees / (size - 1));
        }
    }
    public struct Box
    {
        public Vec2int L;
        public Vec2int R;
        public int HalfLength;
        public int Length;

        public Box(Vec2int L, Vec2int R)
        {
            this.L = L;
            this.R = R;
            Length = R.x - L.x;
            HalfLength = Length / 2;
        }
    }
}
```

> Структура из Global
>   public struct Vec2int
>   {
>      public int x;
>      public int y;
>      public Vec2int(int x, int y)
>      {
>         this.x = x;
>         this.y = y;
>      }
>   }

Answer (score 4):

Смотрите.

Чтобы переделать (нехвостовую) рекурсию в итерацию, нужно использовать явную очередь заданий.

Получаем структуру, реализующую одно задание:

```
struct RecTask
{
    public Vec2int L, R;
    public int l;

    public RecTask(Vec2int L, Vec2int R, int l)
    {
        this.L = L; this.R = R; this.l = l;
    }
}
```

Теперь в коде функции можно явно управлять заданиями:

```
public void diamondSquare(Vec2int L, Vec2int R, int l)
{
    Queue<RecTask> queue = new Queue<RecTask>();
    queue.Enqueue(new RecTask(L, R, l));
    while (queue.Count > 0)
    {
        var task = queue.Dequeue();
        Vec2int[] points = GetPoints(task.L, task.R, task.l);
        foreach (Vec2int elem in points)
        {
            diamond(elem, task.l);
        }
        square(task.L, new Vec2int(points[3].x, points[2].y), task.l);
        square(new Vec2int(points[3].x, points[2].y), task.R, task.l);
        square(points[0], points[1], task.l);
        square(points[3], points[2], l);

        var newL = task.l/2;
        if (newL > 0)
        {
            queue.Enqueue(new RecTask(task.L, new Vec2int(points[3].x, points[2].y), newL));
            queue.Enqueue(new RecTask(new Vec2int(points[3].x, points[2].y), task.R, newL));
            queue.Enqueue(new RecTask(points[0], points[1], newL));
            queue.Enqueue(new RecTask(points[3], points[2], newL));
        }
    }
}
```

При этом решении порядок выполнения заданий немного другой. Если нужно сохранить и порядок, нужно превратить очередь в стек и класть задания в обратном порядке.

```
public void diamondSquare(Vec2int L, Vec2int R, int l)
{
    Stack<RecTask> stack = new Stack<RecTask>();
    stack.Push(new RecTask(L, R, l));
    while (stack.Count > 0)
    {
        var task = stack.Pop();
        Vec2int[] points = GetPoints(L, R, l);
        foreach (Vec2int elem in points)
        {
            diamond(elem, l);
        }
        square(L, new Vec2int(points[3].x, points[2].y), l);
        square(new Vec2int(points[3].x, points[2].y), R, l);
        square(points[0], points[1], l);
        square(points[3], points[2], l);

        var newL = l/2;
        if (newL > 0)
        {
            stack.Push(new RecTask(points[3], points[2], newL));
            stack.Push(new RecTask(points[0], points[1], newL));
            stack.Push(new RecTask(new Vec2int(points[3].x, points[2].y), R, newL));
            stack.Push(new RecTask(L, new Vec2int(points[3].x, points[2].y), newL));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Поправьте меня, если я неправ... Но ведь это - особенно со стеком - по сути прямая эмуляция рекурсии? Обычно рекурсию переводят в итерацию (если я верно понимаю) для ускорения (убираем вызов) и снижения нагрузки на стек (если рекурсия очень глубокая). Как я понимаю, здесь производительность может быть даже меньше, только и того, что нагрузку на стек переносим в динамическую память?...

Comment: @Harry: Ну, производительность по идее должна быть не хуже за счёт того, что мы аллоцируем только данные, а не полноценный стек фрейм. Так что насчёт потери производительности не уверен. Но надо бы попрофилировать, конечно.

Comment: @Harry: А так — да, прямая эмуляция рекурсии. Поэтому и универсальный метод.

Comment: Как получится проанализирую и проверю этот код. Я сейчас немного пробежался глазами, и мне кажется результат будет таким же как и от моей рекурсии. Надеюсь вы понимаете как работает Diamond-Square, в моём варианте проблема в том что уже на 1 рекурсивном вызове одна или даже две точки к которым обращается Diamond(), определяется в следующем рекурсивном вызове функцией Square(). В общем если расписывать в комментах получится много и непонятно. Добавлю самому вопросу.

Comment: @CGLike: Ну да, я не менял смысл кода, просто превратил рекурсивную функцию в итеративную. Код делает в точности то же самое, что и рекурсивный вариант.

Comment: Но все равно спасибо я по разбираю ваш код)